# Using pexpect to control kpcli

Tags: python, pexpect, keepass

I am trying to automate ssh connectivity using keepassdb and I am just starting out the script to interrogate the keypass kpcli shell. I want it to print out the result at the end.

```
# -*- coding: utf -*-
import os,sys
import pexpect
global str
db_kp='/media/sf_VM_shared/passwords.kdb'
pass_kp='KDBPASSWORD'
kp = pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/kpcli')
kp.expect('>')
kp.sendline=('open /media/sf_VM_shared/passwords.kdb')
kp.expect=('Please provide the master password:')
kp.sendline=(pass_kp)
kp.expect('>')
kp.sendline=('cd General/Network/Firewalls/SSH/')
kp.expect=('kpcli:/General/Network/Firewalls/SSH>')
kp.sendline=("show -f 0")
print(kp.before)
```

I am getting the following when trying to run the file:

```
python3 ssh_firewall.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ssh_firewall.py", line 12, in <module>
kp.expect('>')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
kp.expect=('Please provide the master password:')
```

You're replacing the `expect` function, rather than calling it. Take the `=` out:

```
kp.expect('Please provide the master password:')
```

You're doing the same thing with `kp.sendline`, so you'll need to fix that as well.

Comment: Thanks! I get a bit further now. It looks like it gets to the cd command and then drops me out but doesn't print what is in the kpdb file:

     pdvb@pdvb:~$ python3 -d ssh_firewall.py
     b':/> cd General/Network/Firewalls/'

Comment: I'm now getting b':/'

Is there a way to debug?

Comment: I've managed to do this and print the output to a buffer but I am getting unreliable results when using this data, probably because it's in a buffer and unformatted.

       child.sendline('open /media/sf_VM_shared/Paul.kdb')
       child.expect('Please provide the master password:')
       child.sendline(pass_child)
    child.expect('>')
       child.sendline('cd General/Network/Firewalls/SSH')
       child.expect('SSH')
       child.sendline("show -f 0")
       child.expect('Path')
       print(child.buffer)